# Picker is not returning any image if allowsEditing=NO

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

As the title suggests, if I set

`imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;`

to

`imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO`

I get no image returned? I have searched SO and can not find a definitive answer

```
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    [self.editController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
  DebugLog(@"info dict: %@", info);
  [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  self.schemeLogo.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.schemeLogo.image = image;
  NSData *imageData1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
  NSString *path1 = [ICUtils pathForDocument:@"schemeLogo.png"];
  [imageData1 writeToFile:path1 atomically:NO];
}
```

Comment: You will get an image even when allowsEditing is set to NO.  Where is your (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info ?

Comment: Ah, fixed it! thanks for pointing me at  - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed, needed

`[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

Comment: If you do so then you will get original image not edited image. Then what is the benefit to set `allowsEditing = YES` ?

Comment: The question states the original image is what is requred.  The purpose of this is to return the original image.  `allowsEditing = YES` is used when ediitiong is needed.  In this situation it is not.